# Perl dump data from a hash to a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, perl, spreadsheet

I have a hash with key and Values(array). I want to dump them to a spreadsheet

```
%hash
   key1 -> foo bar 
   key2-> john adam gill
   key3-> apple banana mango orange
```

Code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Excel::Writer::XLSX;

my $workbook = Excel::Writer::XLSX->new( 'c:\TEMP\filename.xlsx' ); 
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();

my $row = 1;
my $col = 1;

foreach my $k (keys %hash)
{
    $worksheet->write($row, $col)->{Value} =  $k;                # title
    $worksheet->write($row, $col++,)->{Value} =  $hash{$k};     # value
    $row++;
}
```

**Current Output** 
Can't call method "add_worksheet" on an undefined value
**Desired Output**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `Excel::Writer::XLSX->new` failed. Add this code after calling `new`, to see what went wrong:

```
if (not defined $workbook)
{
    die "Failed to create spreadsheet: $!";
}
```

Comment: Added the code and came to know that its a permission denied error. So added workbook->close() and came out of permission denied error. Now getting output little differently than I need. Updated the code and outputs

Comment: @Jill448 That's an entirely different question. Please create a new post instead of invalidating answers that people have already spent time writing.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Sure will do